# React: Merging formData props to Component's state (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my Editor Component, I monitor form input changes and save them to the state.

When the form is submitted, the state's formData is dispatched to the store, when the Component reloads, I would like to merge the formData from the props (store) to the state.

I've tried using the spread operator with initialState ordered first, then spreading my prop's formData, and the same with spreading my prop first then setting the initialState

I'm failry new to React + Redux, I just can't quite see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance! - Benjamin

```
const initialState =  {
    articles: [],

    formData: {
        articleId: null,
        title: '',
        body: '',
        status: editorTypes.STATUS_DRAFT
    },

    editMode: false,
}

const TITLE = editorTypes.TITLE_DEFAULT
const TYPE = editorTypes.TYPE_ARTICLE

class Editor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const { title, body, status } = this.props.formData

        this.state = {
            title: TITLE,
            formData: {
                title,
                body,
                status,
                TYPE
            },
            ...this.props.initialState
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** added mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { list, refreshList, editMode, formData } = state.dashboard.articles

    return {
        list,
        refreshList,
        editMode,
        formData
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditorWrapper(Editor))
```

Comment: It seems that you are expecting redux to update initialState, which isn't how it works.  In general, you may want to read more about how `mapStateToProps` works.  That's the more conventional way of getting redux state into your component (not trying to merge it with component-local state).

Comment: I tried updating the store using onChange, but it made my browser lag. So I changed it to use the Component state but that's probably not the best way to do things... 

Also I've updated my post with the mapStateToProps function @jmargolisvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Props in Initial State is anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e) , to put the props in the state, you can use :

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...this.props.initialState
    }));
}
```

and to update the `state` when the component updates, you can use [componentdidupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) like :

```
componentdidupdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.initialState !== this.props.initialState){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            formData : {
                ...this.props.formData
            }           
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly correct, but I removed the states and now use props

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand why you are doing this approach as this approach isn't good.
But as for your requirement, You can do one thing.
You can declare `componentDidUpdate` and inside cDU you can check, if the local state form and redux form is different, you can `setState` to the new data. 
Example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
// now you can check your props and state
 if(prevState.formData.articleId === this.props.formData.articleId) {
   // here i only compared your articleId, You can check others yourself or use 
   // Lodash to check your object equity.
   // for example, with loash console.log(_.isEqual(prevState.formData, 
   // this.props.formData));
   this.setState({ formData: this.props.formData});
  }
}
```

This would solve your issue, But I highly recommend to use some other approach.

Comment: Happy to help :)